# How to avoid size accumulation in git repositories while replacing files many times?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a github repository to keep track of a small number of files with relatively small size. However, because of the nature of the task, I have to replace the files with new very frequently. I realized the size of repository is quickly getting big because of that frequent replacement.

Given the fact that I only need the latest version of each file and won't need older versions. How can I avoid this over sizing?

I am following the regular standard git practice to: (1) git add, (2) git commit, (3) git push, in order to replace the older with the new files.

Comment: If the files have the same name, they'll be overridden, and it won't be a problem. Having older versions of a file stored in Git is intentional, plus Git has no file size and no file number limits.

Comment: They are having the same name, and they are getting replaced, BUT IT IS A PROBLEM :) The size of repo including two images and a text file exceeds 150MB!!

Comment: If you are dealing with binary files then it is better to use [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Comment: Images generally don't compress well, because they're already compressed. So if each image is, say, half a megabyte (so that the 2 together are 1 MB) and you make 150 commits that each have a new image-pair, you'll use about 150 MB to hold all versions in a Git repository. But that's precisely what a version control system *is:* it's a place where you store every version of every file *forever*.

Comment: Very true. However, I am thinking how can I still use git to store the latest, but not store all the tracings... (because it's still very useful to store the latest version)

Answer (score 2):

> Given the fact that I only need the latest version of each file and won't need older versions. How can I avoid this over sizing?

Then you don't need a revision control system like `git`.

However, you can probably do what you want. Instead of making a new commit every time you modify a file, just update the existing commit:

- Edit `somefile.txt`
- `git add somefile.txt`
- `git commit --amend`

Using this model, you are replacing one commit with another, you are never growing the history of your repository, and the size of your repository will not grow over time.

---

To get rid of your existing history, just `rm -rf .git`, then re-create the git repository, link it to your GitHub repository with `git remote add`, and `git push -fu origin master`.

Comment: I love this idea. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: wait, is it possible to `git push` and still use this remedy? I need to always have the latest version of the file pushed.

Comment: Sure. You will always need to use `git push -f` because you're replacing history, but that's all.